# Use Laravel auth with driver database

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I would like to use the `auth` function in Laravel 4.2 with a custom table called `pseudo` but I'm getting this error:

> Undefined index: id

The PK of the table is : **id_pseudo**

Here is my auth.php config:

```
'driver' => 'database',
'table' => 'pseudo',
```

Here is my model for the table "pseudo" :

```
class pseudo extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    protected $table = 'pseudo';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_pseudo';

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {

        return $this->id_pseudo;
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
```

Here is my php code:

```
public function authentification()
    {
        $email = Input::get('email');
        $mdp = Input::get('password');

        if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password'), 'code_court_etat' => 'VALIDE'))){

            exit("signature OK");

        } else {
            exit("signature KO");
        }
```

I am sure that the problem is on somewhere into the "model" file, but I do not know what exactly, I am a beginner with laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your auth driver should be `eloquent` as you're trying to use an eloquent model, rather than directly querying the database.

In your `app/config/auth.php` you should also set the model option to the class of your model, in this case `pseudo`

More in the documentation on authentication with 4.2 http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security

Edit as per comments:

As your current model implements both the `UserInterface` and `RemindableInterface` there are several methods your model needs to define for several features of the auth functionality to work.

You can add the following two traits to your model to automatically add the required functions. This assumes you have the following columns on your table: `email`, `password` and `remember_token`

```
use \Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait, \Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
```

Alternatively you can implement these methods yourself if your table uses different column names. See the 2 links below as to what methods need to be added and what they should do.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Auth/UserTrait.php
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Auth/Reminders/RemindableTrait.php

Comment: Ok thanks, I Changed. And now I have another error. Class pseudo contains 6 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods. Sure I am on the right direction.

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain how to correct the further issue.

Comment: I have understood. thanks for your response, all is working fine now.